# The local ring at the origin of $ \Bbb{A}^2 $

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, algebraic-curves

Consider the curves $ F = y-x^3 $ and $ G = y^3-x^4 $ over $ K. $ Find a polynomial representative of $ \frac{1}{1+x} $ in $ \mathscr{O}_0/ \langle F,G \rangle. $ I am having trouble simplifying $ \mathscr{O}_0/ \langle F,G \rangle $. Any hints?

$\mathscr{O}_P = \{\frac{f}{g} | f,g \in k[X,Y], g(P) \neq 0  \}.$

Comment: Quotienting by $y-x^3$ means that you can replace $y$ by $x^3$ everywhere and discard $y$

Comment: you can expand $\frac{1}{1+x}$ as $1-x+x^2-x^3+…$ and then replace $x^3$ by $y$ and $x^4$ by $y^3$, as they represent same class in the quotient

Comment: @reuns So, it's equal to $ x^9 - x^4 $?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the fact that we're quotienting by an ideal containing $y-x^3$ means we can rewrite all instances of $y$ as $x^3$. So $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(y-x^3,y^3-x^4)\cong k[x]_{(x)}/(x^9-x^4)$, and $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is taken to $\frac{1}{1+x}$ under this isomorphism (since it doesn't have any occurances of $y$).

What next? We can simplify a bit. Please try yourself before looking at the spoiler:

> But $x^9-x^4=x^4(x^5-1)$, and $x^5-1$ is a unit in $k[x]_{(x)}$ since it's not in the ideal $(x)$. Therefore the ideal $(x^9-x^4)$ is the same as the ideal $x^4$, and so our ring is isomorphic to $k[x]/(x^4)$.

Now you should be able to finish by finding a polynomial representative. Here's the end of the computation under a spoiler so you can check your work:

> Now it's easy to find a polynomial representative for the inverse: $1-x+x^2-x^3$ will work, as $(1+x)(1-x+x^2-x^3)=1+x-x+x^2-x^2-x^3+x^3-x^4=1$.